# Has "Kinki" become less common than "Kansai" because of the word "kinky"?

Tags: synonyms

According to [Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kinki,Kansai&year_start=1890&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), "Kinki" and "Kansai" (which are pretty [synonymous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_region)) used to be roughly equally common, but Kansai is now more common.

Is this difference statistically different? And if so, what contributed to it? Could the word "kinky" have contributed to it? Google NGram doesn't indicate a [spectacular rise](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kinky&year_start=1890&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for the word, but that could be because it didn't use to be used in a sexual sense, whereas that meaning has become more common over time - I don't know how to measure that though.

The other explanation I can think of is that Japanese people use "Kinki" less nowadays, and that the relative use of "Kinki" versus "Kansai" has spilled over into English.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on Japanese.SE? Neither word is properly an English word, and no one without special knowledge of Japanese would understand what *kansai* means, let alone *kinki* (which, like Shawn Mooney, I've never heard till now).

Comment: @Robusto how do you define what is properly an English word?

Comment: Certainly we use foreign words in English, but if you're trying to claim that *kansai* is an English word (and that this is a question about English on that basis) then you will have to include *kantou*, *chiku*, *kasumigaseki* and others as English words. We have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: So they're place names? In that case I certainly agree that this doesn't belong here!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how any opinion from ELU can possibly be relevant to how the Japanese view their own language and words within it in relation to English words.

Comment: FWIW, I asked a [related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72330/are-%e8%bf%91%e7%95%bf-%e3%81%8d%e3%82%93%e3%81%8d-and-%e9%96%a2%e8%a5%bf-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%93%e3%81%95%e3%81%84-two-nouns-for-the-same-concept-and-same-region-or-there) at Japanese SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can combine your two observations into the same query, thus:

[image]

And while *kinky* has been more common than either *Kinki* or *Kansai* in English, the rise of *kinky* does seem to correspond with the decline of *Kinki* pretty strongly.

Other factors could include earlier texts being more likely to have one misread by the other by google's OCR, but it seems a reasonable conclusion.

Quite aside from the connotations being inappropriate, avoiding homophones is always a reason to favour one synonym over another.

Others though include the simple fact of which is more often seen by readers leading words to be one of the cases where nothing succeeds like success, or the simple fact that the latter just looks more Japanese to an English-speaking reader. Certainly, I immediately thought that *Kansai* looked like a Japanese word, but didn't have the same reaction to *Kinki*, so that would be a reason in itself to favour it for an English-speaking audience. Connotations will still help too of course (I don't care how many relatives my partner has called *Bent*, I'm not naming any future son that if he's going to live in an English-speaking country).

However, "関西地方" gives me more google results than "近畿地方", and while some are clearly google knowing they're synonyms, that does suggest that *Kansai* is more popular than *Kinki* in Japanese too, which would hence be a source of comparative popularity when used in English.

It's possible that knowledge of the English has even affected the Japanese preference, though we'd need similar data in Japanese to even begin to judge the possibility.

So in all, I think we can say that the similarity to an English word is certainly a very plausible as *a* reason for favouring one over the other, but it's not proven, and certainly not proven as the only reason.

Comment: Ngrams don't always tell the whole story, of course, but, in this case, the behavior of the blue and green lines during the late 1960s seems very telling. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew, I have been living in Tokyo for 4 years, have tons of friends and students from the Kansai region, and have visited the area several times.  For what it's worth, I have never heard Kinki used as a synonym for Kansai until I read your post and clicked on the wikipedia link.